# Ubuntu slow boot after swap removing

Tags: boot, swap

Recently my Ubuntu 18.04 is booting slowly. I deleted a swap are which is inside another HDD drive from the "Disks" in menu, then treats and boots normally, up to now. Now, every time I boot my computer, it always waits me 90 seconds for looking an address of swap area, that is:

```
# swap was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=4f0ffd17-688f-44da-98fa-f2e90c517000 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

What should I do? I do not have any swap area.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpUwc.jpg)

[image: UUID's and swap areas]

[The older fstab file, I found a copy of it in trash bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y215.png)

Comment: Are you saying that you no longer have a swap partition?

Comment: yes, but i deleted it by using gui, menu-disks. I formatted it and changed its type of the partition.

Comment: Did you remember to edit /etc/fstab to reflect the change?

Comment: I only changed its type. I looked the swaps UUID from there, i did not edit anything in that text.

Comment: Do you currently (today) have a swap partition, a swapfile, or no swap at all?

Comment: I do not have any swap partition or a swap file.

Comment: Then remove the swap line from /etc/fstab. Likely that small change will fix your problem.

Comment: Problem is solved after deleting that lines, thank you :)

Comment: So, the $64,000 question... why did you delete your swap partition? Every Linux/Ubuntu computer needs a swap partition or /swapfile. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: I first set the linux up on a hdd drive that lies next to the windows system. The issue was deleting swap was its swap. When i get my additional ssd for linux, i deleted the linux in hdd and i set a new ubuntu to my ssd. Hdd partition of swap restricted my disk space in the windows' hdd, therefore i deleted it. Also i did not want to have swap area in another disk.

Comment: @heynnema you may look at the last comment i sent

Comment: So what have we learned today? You can't just delete stuff without knowing the consequences. Yes, after deleting the swap partition on the HDD, the problem is in your /etc/fstab. However, now that you've deleted the swap partition, and edited out the swap mount in /etc/fstab, you're only half way there. You need a swap on the SSD. Depending on how you installed Ubuntu, it may already be there in the form of a /swapfile (but that should be defined in /etc/fstab also). So, edit your question and show me `free -h` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @heynnema I edited the post, you can see either the new or old fstab files, and thanks for help :)

Comment: You have no swap partition and no /swapfile. You need one or the other. My understanding is that you didn't want a swap partition on the HDD. On the SSD we can either do a swap partition (needed if you hibernate), or a /swapfile. What's your preference?

Comment: Yes, I prefer swap area on ssd because other hdd is ntfs and i have windows10 ubuntu18.04.3 dual boot. I thought it was not critical need for my ubuntu up to now. Now i decided creating a new swap partition on appropriate conditions in my ssd. That is my preference. @heynnema

Comment: Create a 5G swap partition on SSD. Initialize it as swap. `sudo blkid` to get the UUID, then edit /etc/fstab. Then `sudo swapon -a`. Then do `free -h` to confirm swap.

Comment: Thanks for help @heynnema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUID of a partition changes when you format it.  The UUID of the deleted swap partition in your fstab is not valid.  Change it to the current UUID of the partition.

Comment: Which partition should i point then? There isn't any swap file or swap partition in my computer currently.

Comment: After deleting that garbage UUID from /etc/fstab, problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq provides good information on swap file management